# Transposition cypher that uses Vigenere table

Tags: transposition-cipher

I have difficulty understanding the difference between two cyphers that both use Vigenere table and transposition, here is examples of both:

The key for the system is the key pair $k_1, k_2$, where $k_1 - $ slogan (witch contains no same letters) and $k_2 \in Z_m $. Then transposition rule can be defined as:

$$\phi(k_1) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 &2&3&...& m-1 \\ s &l & o &g &... & z_{m-1} \end{matrix}\right)$$

where $z_i \in Z_m$ differ from slogan and usually ordered alphabetically.
Latin square substitution is defined by $T^{i} \circ \phi(k_1), \ i = 1,2, ..., m-1$.
Example: slogan is given as: B,D,A, alphabet used to cypher is A,B,C,D,E,F. Then the Viginere table for all possible $i = k_2$ is:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}\ i & A &B&C&D&E&F \\ 0 & B&D&A&C&E&F \\ 1&C&E&B&D&F&A \\ 2&D&F&C&E&A&B \\ 3& E&A&D&F&B&C\\4&F&B&E&A&C&D\\5&A&C&F&B&D&E\end{matrix}\right)$$

But in case the key is given as a bijection: X: $\left(\begin{matrix}A&B&C&D \\ C&A&D&B\end{matrix}\right)$ The composition of Viginere table nd the X would be:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}i &A&B&C&D \\ 0 &C&A&D&B  \\ 1 & A &D&B&C \\ 2 &D&B&C&A \\ 3 & B&C&A&D\end{matrix}\right)$$

In the first example, The order of the alphabet is defined in first row: A,B,C,D,E,F. But in the second example the alphabet is first shifted to become C A D B. I don't understand the difference between these two methods as they seem identical only with the difference that the first ones key has this slogan. Can someone explain?